# Querying objects in MongoDB that have no value just their key?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoClient in node.js, no other modules like mongoose etc.

**1)** Right now I am inserting information by retrieving information from an API, JSON.parse-ing it and then storing it in the DB `db.collection.insert(object)`. Now this works perfectly, here's a short preview of how the data I am retrieving looks like:

```
{"hatenames":
    {"id":6239,
     "name":"hatenames",
     "stat1":659,
     "stat2":30,
     "stat3":1414693
    }
}
```

What makes me question if I am doing it right though is, in MongoVUE I see it stores the document hatenames, but for value it's just blank, here's an image of it:
[image: example]

So the value is just blank. This is giving me trouble with finding it in the DB. I have tried the following: `collection.findOne( { queryObject : null }`, this will always return the first key in my database, possibly because the value is empty, but no matter what I search for, it will always return hatenames even though I'm not searching for it. I have searched and read a lot about find in mongodb but I must be missing something because the only other option I've found is `collection.findOne( {queryObject : {$exists : true } }` but this option never finds anything. This would all be easy if I could just do `db.collection.findOne( queryObject )`, but that doesn't work, it says 'query selector must be an object'. How should I go about finding it?

**2)** Another bonus question if you don't mind, for around 20 million+ documents that will be query'd based off names, is it best to have just 1 database? Or should I split it by letters and have 27 databases? Or even crazier, have 27x27 and go by first 2 letters of the name? Last ones a little overkill but figured I'd ask.

Any other tips are welcome, thanks for reading.

Comment: What is `queryObject`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Sorry for not specifying, queryObject is just the name that it's searching for, in this case it would be hatenames. I am trying to successfully return the key being searched

Comment: This is really confusing.  What do you mean by "return the key being searched"? Are you confusing keys and documents?

Comment: Ah you are totally right, I wasn't look at Type on the right side, really sorry about that I only started using databases yesterday. I did mean search for the document hatenames, which is actually a variable attained from whatever name the user searches. I am trying to find it and return the document from the database. Hope that makes more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have an empty value for a key in mongodb because it uses [bson](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) (binary json) to store data. And in [json](http://www.json.org/)

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins
>   with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is
>   followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by ,
>   (comma).

In your case `hatenames` is a key which has an object `{"id":6239, "name":"hatenames", "stat1":659, "stat2":30, "stat3":1414693}` as a value.

I would suggest you to read documentation and [use cases](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/) because it looks like you just started with mongo and have some problems understanding its model.

Comment: Hello again Salvador, and thank you for your help yesterday. Sorry for the basic and boring question. I looked over most of the pages on use cases, and read the ones that I thought might pertain to my problem. Unfortunately, to be honest, there are so many keywords I don't even understand, I am a self-taught hobby~ist wannabe programmer. I'm more of a dumb stubborn type that keeps trying and learns from trial and error. Regarding what you said, I still wasn't able to return any value or make the find work. I tried `db.coll.findOne({queryObject:"id"}`, `db.coll.findOne({queryObject:6239}`,

Comment: `db.coll.findOne({queryObject:{}}`, but neither worked. I really thought at least one of those would work if the entire part was the value. I keep going over the docs for find and findOne, but they all require an object syntax { field1 : field2 }, but everything I've tried I still cant find what to put in field2. In field1 I put the username being searched aka queryObject which is hatenames in this case, a var doesn't even work for field2 as far as I know, but regardless what I've tried I just can't make it return all the values, or even one.

Comment: @HateNames based on my understanding of your problem, you need to find documents based on the subdocument field. Take a look at [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). and try to do `db.coll.findOne({'hatenames.id': 6239})`

Comment: While that example works, I need to be able to dynamically search for fields, depending what the user searches, which will always be a name. I tried `db.coll.findOne({queryObject + '.id':6239})` but that didn't work any more hehe. The name and id will always be different tho. I finally realized from your example that this really is just a find. I always thought if I search for the id it will only return the value of id, but it returns the entire thing. The values will always be unique though, I don't see what I can put in field2 to allow me to find it. btw I love your chessheaven puzzles

Comment: @HateNames in this case I would suggest you to change the collection schema, because with the current one it is hard to do what you want. As for chessheaven, glad that you liked it. I am planning to opensource it.

Comment: I just thought about it but, is the way I'm storing my document wrong for finding it afterwards?

Comment: Oh, awesome, I will look into that right away, thank you once again for your help, sorry for the trouble.